# Which is the difference between the Full content and the Default mode?

Tags: 8, forms

The FieldUI uses the **default** as default value for entity form/view displays. But the EntityViewBuilderInterface uses the **full** as default value.

Also template_preprocess_taxonomy_term() uses the **full** value to find out if the current page is taxonomy term.

So which one should I look for to know if "default" mode is being used? Should I be checking both values?

I think this applies to D7 too but I'm working with D8 so I'm looking for information within this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for EntityViewBuilderInterface is $view_mode.

View displays and view modes are *not* the same thing.

view_mode can basically be anything you want, you can even make up them on the fly.

What the field formatter/widget system then does is look up if there is a form/view display with for that view mode. If that is the case, that is used.  If not, then it falls back to `default`.

The view/form modes that you set up in the UI are basically only there to tell field UI that it can create form/view displays for them (the checkboxes at the bottom of the default display page). They are never used at runtime.

So, when you are going to node/1, there is by default no display for `full`, so it falls back to default. Whereas `teaser` does have one, so it uses different things. However, you can also enable a form display for `full` and then it will no longer use `default`.

Comment: Thanks. So based on your answer the "default" is the fall-back view mode :D

Comment: No. default is the fallback view *display*. view modes don't have fallbacks.

Comment: Thanks, it's very clear, **node.full** will fall back to **node.default** display

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between default and full, they are essentially the same thing. "Full" is just a view mode and for some entities that is the "Default" view mode (not all though). Follows is more information like how to get the information that you are looking for in the correct way. I thought about removing the answer but I actually needed this information not too long ago and this may help someone else looking for a similar answer. With the question being a little vague it's hard to answer without making a guess at what is actually needed. If this is not what you are needing please let me know and I will update my answer accordingly.

Here is the view modes docs for explanation of different view modes in Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/node/2511722

In Drupal 7 you would use something like this ([entity_get_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7)):

```
$entity_info = entity_get_info('node');
dpm(array_keys($entity_info['view modes']));
```

That would return information like below:

```
array (
  0 => 'full',
  1 => 'teaser',
  2 => 'rss',
  3 => 'search_index',
  4 => 'search_result',
)
```

But Drupal 8 that function is deprecated (see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1929006) for more information.

So you would use code from the EntityManagerInterface:

```
/**
 * Gets the entity definition for an entity type.
 *
 * @param string|null $entity_type
 *   (optional) The entity type (e.g. 'node'). Leave NULL to retrieve
 *   information for all entity types.
 *
 * @return array
 *   An array containing the entity type's definition, as retrieved with
 *   \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface. If $entity_type is NULL, an
 *   associative array of all entity type definitions keyed by entity type is
 *   returned.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface
 * @see hook_entity_info_alter()
 */

$allEntities = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinitions();

$nodeEntity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition('node');

dpm($nodeEntity);
```

You should be able to use devel to find out what the view mode is set to with the above code. These would ensure you are getting the correct view mode for whatever entity you are needing the information for at the time as the others that you have tried are returning information from different places and may not give you the correct results or results you need at the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a page named [Display Modes, View Modes, and Form Modes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes) that explain this a little.

***Display modes***

> Display modes (found at admin/structure/display-modes) exist to
>   provide different presentations of Content Entities for either viewing
>   or editing. The two types of display modes are "view modes" and "form
>   modes."

***View modes and view displays***

> On this page (/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display) a site
>   builder has the option to enable customized field display settings for
>   the bundle (field order and field formatter usage) on a per view mode
>   basis. It is not required that all view modes have specific
>   customizations made for all bundles. In this example, only the view
>   modes “RSS” and “Teaser” have their own specific settings. All other
>   view modes fall back to the “default” configuration. The association
>   between an entity type bundle and view mode is called a ***View Display***.
>   @see EntityViewDisplayInterface